# Laravel Route custom route instead of resource

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I am trying to get a custom link from my view to my AdminOfficesController. However for some reason it just gives me a blank page with no errors or whatsoever. Tried to desbug it using the docs, stackoverflow and debugging but I remain clueless of why it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

In my view I have the following link:

```
                    <a href="{{ url('admin/offices/' . $customer->id)  }}">
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Create office</button>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

In my routes I have the following code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('/auth/login');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
Route::resource('admin/customers', 'AdminCustomersController');
Route::resource('admin/offices', 'AdminOfficesController');
Route::resource('admin/labourentries', 'AdminLabourentriesController');
Route::resource('admin/labourtypes', 'AdminLabourtypesController');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminCustomersController@dashboard');
Route::get('admin/offices/{customer_id}/create',  'AdminOfficesController@create');
```

And my controller contains the following code:

```
public function create()
{
    echo "hi";
    return view('admin.offices.create');
}
```

I'm probably missing something very simple in my view or route file, but I honestly don't see it. My controller's other functions like index etc is working fine.

Thanks for the help .
Rodney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could name your routes:

```html
Route::get('/admin/offices/{customer_id}/create', [
    'as' => 'admin.offices.customer.create,
    'uses' => 'AdminOfficesController@create'
]);
```

And use it like this

```html
<a href="{{URL::route('admin.offices.client.create', array($customer->id))}}">
```

Comment: You are welcome, actually Md. Sahadat alfo catched a mistake you made.

But using named routes is the way to go, so this is preferable

Answer (score 1):

Your button is:

```
                <a href="{{ url('admin/offices/' . $customer->id)  }}">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Create office</button>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

Your route is:

`admin/offices/{customer_id}/create`

You forget `/create`

I would recommand you to use names for your routes (more on laravel docs), since if you change the `URL` every route will have the new URL without any changes

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/offices/' . $customer->id.'/create')  }}">
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Create office</button>
                        </div>
                    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Route resources are just a convenience to keep your code dry, but if you need to make changes, you could always use the full code instead and change it at will.

```
Route::get('resource', ['as' => 'resource.index', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@index']);
Route::get('resource/create', ['as' => 'resource.create', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@create']);
Route::post('resource', ['as' => 'resource.store', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@store']);
Route::get('resource/{resource}', ['as' => 'resource.show', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@show']);
Route::get('resource/{resource}/edit', ['as' => 'resource.edit', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@edit']);
Route::put('resource/{resource}', ['as' => 'resource.update', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@update']);
Route::patch('resource/{resource}', ['uses' => 'ResourcesController@update']);
Route::delete('resource/{resource}', ['as' => 'resource.destroy', 'uses' => 'ResourcesController@destroy']);
```